# How do I change the shape of item border in navbar

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how can I get this shape when the current page is displayed
[image]

My current code goes like this:

```
current {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

But text goes sideways aswell

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you apply the opposite skew on an inner element, then the text will become unskewed.

```css
.current {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.text {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="current">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```css
.box{
display: inline-block;
padding: 12px 64px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">text</div>
```

Comment: those 2 links can be useful to your answer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path &  https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/